# How do I add a header to a Django RequestFactory request?

Tags: django, unit-testing, http-headers

To manually send a GET request with a header, I do this with `curl`:

```
curl http://example.com/endpoint -H "Key: Value"
```

I want to write a unit test that makes a request (using `django.test.RequestFactory`) containing a header. How can I add a header to the request?

For clarity, below is an example of what I'd *like* to be able to do, though what I have written below is *not* valid code because `RequestFactory.get()` does not have a `headers` parameter:

```
from django.test import TestCase, RequestFactory


class TestClassForMyDjangoApp(TestCase):
    def test_for_my_app(self):
        factory = RequestFactory()
        
        my_header = dict(key=value, another_key=another_value)
        factory.get('/endpoint/', headers=my_header)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to pass ***`HTTP_*`*** kwargs to the `get(...)` ( or any valid http methods) to pass a custom HTTP header in the request.

```
class TestClassForMyDjangoApp(TestCase):
    def test_for_my_app(self):
        factory = RequestFactory()
        my_header = {"HTTP_CUSTOM_KEY": "VALUE"}
        request = factory.get("/some/url/", **my_header)
        print(request.headers) # {'Custom-Key': 'VALUE'}
```

Comment: is there a reference to this in django's documentation?

Comment: Yes, here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.get
Look for the keyword arguments passed as `**extra`.